# Using the Facebook Graphi API, how can I retrieve paginated photos in which my friends are tagged from a specific album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to show the photos of an album in my app. Using the graph API i am able to filter and page by month, like below, which is great. I loop trough the results and get the photo for each id. Best of all, the GRAPH API also gives me a 'next' and 'previous' paging link. Very useful.

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[photo-album-id]/photos/?fields=id&limit=6&since=last month
```

But now i want to retrieve only those ids filter in two ways:

1. Only retrieve those in which the user is tagged
2. Only retrieve those in which the user & his/her friends are tagged.

I couldn't find any way to do this, with the graph API. Is there an alternative via FQL, that still has the paging in there?

Last alternative I can think of is program is in FQL, and do the paging myself.

p.s. I am doing this in Javascript currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve photos the current user is tagged in in a specific album with this `FQL` call:

```
select object_id, src, album_object_id from photo where pid in (select pid from photo_tag where subject=me()) and  and album_object_id=somenumber
```

To retrieve photos in which the user's friends are tagged, for a specific album:

```
select object_id, src, album_object_id from photo where pid in (select pid from photo_tag where subject in (select uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())) and album_object_id=somenumber
```

As far as I know these results will not be paginated. For a detailed take on how to paginate fb queries see the Facebook Developer Blog: [How-To: Paging with the Graph API and FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/)

Comment: I used your proposal to use FQL. I've added limit & offset indeed. Thanks for this. The second FQL call I am still working on, it returns an empty array for me.

Comment: Re the empty array, check you have all the permissions. See Permissions section here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag

Comment: Also, the second query is for a specific album. If there are no tags of friends in that albums the response will be empty. You can get all tags (not album specific) by removing the "and album_object_id=somenumber" at the end, for testing.

Answer (score 0):

After a little play with the Graph Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) I come up with this solution. You can make a call to Graph API as follows

/me?fields=friends.limit(5).fields(photos.limit(5))

The first limit is for how many friends you want to get and the second limit is how many photos you want from each friend.

At the end of the data there already is the next page URL.
I only tested on the explorer but should work.

Hope that helps,
Doruk